# apache mysql forgot password

Tags: mysql, apache, ubuntu, forgot-password

I had setup a password when I installed apache, mysql etc. and now I forgot it. How can I change it? Maybe create a new account? I just need access to the database.

***EDIT***: I'm using it on ubuntu

***EDIT*** : I'd be okay with a destructive way also. i.e. uninstall everyting then reinstall everything but that's also asking password and I don't want to reinstall the whole OS. :(

Comment: wrong place to ask. You probably should reinstall.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : reinstall also asks password of sql :(

Comment: @prongs: just take a look at the answers you got how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in the MySQL manual.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: I'm following this as you said:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-unix but I can't find .pid file in either of /var/lib/mysql , /var/run/mysqld, /usr/local/mysql/data . What do I do?

Comment: Assuming you're running under a *nix based OS, you should be able to work out the location of the pid file from the init.d script, or from /etc/my.cnf.

Comment: You should be able to find the pid by executing `ps -eaf | grep mysqld | grep pid`.

Answer (score 0):

regarding the **root** password take a look here:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/resetting-permissions.html

in case you are a **user**, ask the DB admin for a new one.

Comment: No, it's my own computer. I have `sudo` access to it.

Comment: then you have to go the "root" way ;) for ubuntu you have to follow the UNIX subchapter of the provided link.

Comment: 'm following this: dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/… but I can't find .pid file in either of /var/lib/mysql , /var/run/mysqld, /usr/local/mysql/data . What do I do?